# Sending more than one variables from client to server through socket

Tags: java, sockets

I recently learned about sockets in Java and sending information back and forth from client to server through sockets.
What I want to achieve is sending 'username' and 'password' from client to server and then have these variables checked against the data in a database.

What would the best way be of sending the values of these two separate values to the server so that it can be verified server side?

client side

```
clientSocket = new Socket("192.168.56.1", 7777);

        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);


    //starting the thread
    while(runner == null)
    {
        runner = new Thread(this);

        runner.start();
    }
}
public void run()
{
    String userNameAdminLogin;
    String passwordAdminLogin;
    while(runner == Thread.currentThread())
    {
        userNameAdminLogin = txtUserName.getText();
        passwordAdminLogin = txtPassword.getText();

        out.println(userNameAdminLogin);
        out.println(passwordAdminLogin);
    }
```

sever side

```
while(listening)
            {
                clientSocket = ServerSoc.accept();


                in = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());

                BufferedReader is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

                os = new PrintStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

                //How can I save the two seperate cases of data in variables on server side?
                System.out.println(is.readLine());

            }
```

Kind regards

Arian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're writing two lines on one side, you should obviously read two lines on the other side:

```
String name = is.readLine();
String password = is.readLine();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can have an object which has got username and password as its attributes.

Serialize the object and then send it .

```
class User implements Serializable {  
String userName ;
String Password ;
... 
}
```

Now use ObjectInput/OutputStream to read / write objects

Refer to this for more info - http://www.coderanch.com/t/205325/sockets/java/send-any-java-Object-through

Answer (score 2):

if you use an ObjectOutputStream you can write entire objects.

Those objects have to be serializable